# KendoChart: Missing data does not cause "spacing" on x-axis

Tags: kendo-chart

e.g. if my data is:

```
    "Time":"12:00 AM", "Temp":90,
    "Time":"12:01 AM", "Temp":91,
    "Time":"12:02 AM", "Temp":92,
    "Time":"12:05 AM", "Temp":95
```

Then I would expect the "12:05" value (95) to be spaced over by 3 seconds on the x axis.
Instead, it's right next to the 12:02 value (92).

As of now, I'm forcing such spacing by inserting nulls:

```
    "Time":"12:00 AM", "Temp":90,
    "Time":"12:01 AM", "Temp":91,
    "Time":"12:02 AM", "Temp":92,
    "Time":"12:03 AM", "Temp":null,
    "Time":"12:04 AM", "Temp":null,
    "Time":"12:05 AM", "Temp":95
```

But is there not a better way ??

Note I removed the brackets ({ / }) above, as including them triggered "appears to be invalid code" errors.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution but this might help: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.missingValues

The gist is, configure your chart with `missingValues: "gap"` and Kendo should add the missing gaps.

Note that this will make the chart have gaps on it, as in, where there are missing values, your chart will have a "hole". If you want a continuous chart, then the default "interpolation" option should help you there. I just assumed that's not what you wanted, since it should already be doing that by default and thus you wouldn't ask about it.

Comment: I believe this response to be incorrect. "gap" will cause an interrupted line for missing y-values (so no interpolating), but it will not add missing x-values. Or someone correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: I think you would need "interpolate" as the option rather than "gap". That is in the link @borfast provided.

Comment: Well, I suppose it depends on what you want to see on your graph. When the OP said «Then I would expect the "12:05" value (95) to be spaced over by 3 seconds on the x axis» I assumed he meant he didn't want to see anything on that 3 seconds interval. If you do want to have a continuous chart, then yes, 'interpolate' would be the option you want, but that should be the default anyway. I'll edit my answer to make this clearer. Sorry for not replying to your comment, @PeterB; I don't think I saw the notification for it.